# How to use PIVOT and JOIN together in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, pivot-table

This is table 'VendorItemPricing'.

```
ItemID  VendorName     VendorPrice    
122     HP             215.13
122     IBM            264.41
122     Microsoft      257.65
```

I used this query to get make rows as columns.

```
Select ItemID,
[HP] As HPPrice ,
[Apple] As ApplePrice,
[Microsoft] As MicrosoftPrice,
[IBM] As IBMPrice from (
select ItemID,VendorName,VendorPrice from VendorItemPricing where ItemID = 122)A
PIVOT(MAX(VendorPrice) FOR VendorName IN ([HP],[Apple],Microsoft,IBM))P
```

And this's the output as I expected.

```
ItemID  HPPrice  ApplePrice  MicrosoftPrice  IBMPrice
122     215.13   NULL        257.65          264.41
```

This is my table 'MasterItems', and i used this query to get below results.

```
select ItemID, ItemPartNumber, ItemDescription, CreatedDate, InitialPrice from MasterItems where ItemID = 122
```

This's the result probably.

```
ItemID  ItemPartNumber  ItemDescription  CreatedDate                InitialPrice
122     AB246VB         Volt Fuser Kit   2015-05-15 17:17:32.940    215.14
```

Is it possible to join both results and get results like below?

```
ItemID  ItemPartNumber  ItemDescription  CreatedDate                InitialPrice    HPPrice    ApplePrice   MicrosoftPrice   IBMPrice
122     AB246VB         Volt Fuser Kit   2015-05-15 17:17:32.940    215.14          215.13     NULL         257.65           264.41
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply perform a join in the source table of the `PIVOT`:

```
Select ItemID, ItemPartNumber, ItemDescription, CreatedDate, InitialPrice,
       [HP] As HPPrice, 
       [Apple] As ApplePrice, 
       [Microsoft] As MicrosoftPrice,
       [IBM] As IBMPrice 
from (
   select v.ItemID, VendorName, VendorPrice, 
          ItemPartNumber, ItemDescription, CreatedDate, InitialPrice
   from VendorItemPricing as v 
   left join MasterItems as m on v.ItemID = m.ItemID
   where v.ItemID = 122)A
PIVOT(
   MAX(VendorPrice) 
   FOR VendorName IN ([HP],[Apple],Microsoft,IBM)
)P
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9b12/1)

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming with sample data as you said master table joining with pivot set result using CTE**

```
declare  @table  table (Itemid Int,Vendorname varchar(10),VendorPrice DECIMAL(18,2))
insert into @table (Itemid,Vendorname,VendorPrice)
values (122,'HP',125.66),
(122,'microsoft',134.00),
(122,'IBM',124.90)

Declare @master table (Itemid int,Partnumber Varchar(10),Description varchar(20),Created datetime,InitialPrice decimal(18,2))
insert into @master (Itemid,Partnumber,Description,Created,InitialPrice)values (122,'AB246VB','Volt Fuser Kit',GETDATE(),215.14)

;with cte as (
Select Itemid,[HP] As HPPrice ,
[Apple] As ApplePrice,
[microsoft] As microsoftPrice,
[IBM] As IBMPrice from (
select Itemid,Vendorname,VendorPrice from @table where ItemID = 122)A
PIVOT(MAX(VendorPrice) FOR Vendorname IN ([HP],[Apple],[microsoft],[IBM]))P)
select t.Itemid,
t.Partnumber,
t.Description,
t.Created,
t.InitialPrice,
c.HPPrice,c.ApplePrice,
c.IBMPrice,
c.microsoftPrice from  @master t,cte c where t.ItemID = 122
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT M.*, [HP] As HPPrice, 
       [Apple] As ApplePrice, 
       [Microsoft] As MicrosoftPrice,
       [IBM] As IBMPrice
FROM MasterItems M
JOIN (
    select ItemID,VendorName,VendorPrice from VendorItemPricing where ItemID = 122
)A
PIVOT(MAX(VendorPrice) FOR VendorName IN ([HP],[Apple],Microsoft,IBM)) P
ON M.ItemId = P.ItemId
```

You may adjust JOIN to LEFT JOIN based on your requirement.